# Dojo cache issue

Tags: dojo

I am using dojo i18n:

```
dojo.requireLocalization("scripts", "scprop");
var nls = dojo.i18n.getLocalization("scripts", "scprop");
```

to get text from `nls.keyname` and it is working fine.

When resource bundle changed (adding/removing keys), new bundle is not loading - still loading old bundle from cache. How to reload the new bundle. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the dojo source code to fix this.  This was done on the 1.8.x codebase.  Not sure what the 1.9.x codebase looks like.

`dojo/i18n.js ~line 444`

```
// MODIFIED: append a query parameter to handle caching of 
//    modules/resource bundles by product version
var modUrl = url + '?dojo.cache=' + 
    encodeURIComponent(dojo.config.loadURIVersion || dojo.version.revision);
// ****************************************************************************

xhr.get({
    url:modUrl, // MODIFIED
    sync:true,
    load:load,
    error:function(){
        results.push(cache[url] = {});
    }
});
```

Comment: hi Craig,
is there any other way to prevent caching?

Comment: You could configure the caching on your web server for the file...maybe.